# pyuic5 command not found , I did everthing and still get this same error

Tags: python, pyqt

I installed the designer from sourcefourge.net and installed the packages using pip , i also have the pyuic5.exe file in my scripts file , iam really confused
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. In my case, for some reason, .ui file was crashed. So, I saved .ui file again in QT Design and run again the command into the files directory:

```
pyuic -x file.ui -o file.py
```

This solved my problem.

[]'s